# failed to execute 'put' on 'idbobjectstore' evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value

Tags: angularjs, html, indexeddb

A chrome based APP which I am supporting gives us this error.
I tried to find out more about the error but was unsuccessful.
Can someone kindly explain me on what could be the cause of this.

The Error is as below Image

[image]

The put is happening at this snippet
 var ydbRequest = ydbStorage.put(dbName, data);
The dbName: OUTLETS
and the data value is:

```
1.  Action: "Submit"
2.  ChannelGroup: "ZC03"
3.  City: "LA"
4.  CreateDate: Fri Jun 24 2016 10:23:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
5.  MUValue: Object
6.  ModifiedDate: Mon Jun 27 2016 11:16:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
7.  Mu: "U39 "
8.  Name: "54321"
9.  OutletId: "0000054321"
10. OutletImage: ""
11. Promotion: Object
12. SignatureImage: "data:image/png;base64,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"
13. State: "NV"
14. Status: "Signed"
15. Street: "11 ABC"
16. TargetCMAID: "54AAFF2ECAFF4410E1008000A7692971"
17. Year: 2015
18. ZipCode: "89201"
19. _disabledStates: Object
20. _displayOrderLimit: Object
21. _recallState: "fsop.outlet.review-sign.summary"
22. _validationStates: Object
23. __proto__: Object
```

Let me know in case I need to add more details.

TIA

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 22):

If your object store has a key path, the object being stored must contain a value pointed at by that key path *or* must use a key generator (`{autoIncrement: true}`).

For example:

```
var store = db.createObjectStore('my_store', {keyPath: 'key'});
store.put({key: 11, value: 33}); // OK
store.put({value: 66}); // throws, since 'key' is not present

var store = db.createObjectStore('my_store', {keyPath: 'key', autoIncrement: true});
store.put({key: 11, value: 33}); // OK, key generator set to 11
store.put({value: 66}); // OK, will have auto-generated key 12
```

Comment: Hey Josh, I am confused about the line `store.put({key: 1, value: 33}); ` as in how does that bump the key to 33? Did you mean  `store.put({key: 33, value: 'something'}); ` in that example? Or maybe I completely missed the boat here and would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, must have been half asleep. I'll fix the example.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaBell  Thanks for your response.
I understand that we are putting a value in the given key and in the scenario which I am facing, I have added the key and value details. I am not able to understand if there is any issue with the Value(data in this case) or could it be an issue with dbName

Comment: @Josh Tagging you as well. Kindly Help with your suggestion

Comment: @JoyShashreek - if you need more help you'll need to provide a subset of your actual code, e.g. the code that creates the object store, and the code trying to store a value with a full JSON serialization if possible, so we can point out where the error is.